# Could not load file or assembly Operation is not supported. ONLY during publish but it builds fine

Tags: visual-studio-2019, publish, visual-studio-2022

There are quite a few solutions out there for this one but they all pertain to the actual IIS box. I am Unable to publish at all the publish process fails with the following error:

Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Users\user\Documents\VSSolutions\myWebApp\myWebApp\bin\AjaxControlToolkit.dll' or one of its dependencies. Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515)

I CAN and successfully do build/run and test the app on my local machine.

This is an isolated problem to my specific machine as in my other developers are able to do the publish after I check in all of my changes!

Here is everything that I have tried.

- enabled 32 bit on IIS
- gave full rights to Temporary ASP.NEt folder at several different locations based on offered solutions
- dll file is NOT blocked!

I am using VS 2022 AND VS 2019 and the same issue persists on both!

Please help :)

Answer (score 0):

I saw another Stack Overflow post to make sure anti-virus is not blocking a temporary ASP.NET folder. In my case turns out that was the case indeed. Anti-virus was blocking my publish from completing...